# Energy Analysis of Niagara Falls in Linus Pauling's "General Chemistry"

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation

I just started reading Linus Pauling's "General Chemistry" and the first example confuses me.  He writes:

> **Example 1-1.** Niagara Falls (Horseshoe) is 160 feet high.  How much warmer is the water at the bottom than at the top, as the result of the conversion of potential energy into thermal energy? The standard acceleration of gravity is 9.80665 m s$^{-2}$.
>
> **Solution.** The gravitational force on a mass of 1 kg at the earth's surface is 9.80665 N.  The change is [sic] potential energy of 1 kg over a vertical distance $h$ (in meters) is 9.80665 $\times$ $h$ J.  In this problem $h$ has the value 0.3048 $\times$ 160 = 48.77 m (conversion factor from Appendix I); hence the change in potential energy produces 9.80665 $\times$ 48.77 = 478 J to thermal energy.  The energy required to raise the temperature of 1 kg of water by 1$^{\circ}$C is given above as 1 kcal = 4.184 kJ = 4184 J. Hence the increase in temperature of the water is 478/4184 = 0.114$^{\circ}$C.

Now what I don't understand is why he doesn't account for change in kinetic energy and heat flow between the water and the environment.

If this question belongs on Chemistry.SE, feel free to move it.

Comment: Having grown up in Niagara Falls, I can tell you that the water at the bottom is definitely colder than the water at the top. He must have forgotten to include convective cooling as the water falls through air.

Comment: Wow so I was right to be skeptical!

Comment: The change in kinetic energy *does* get accounted for when you compute the potential difference and convert it to heat; the implication is that the potential energy gets turned to kinetic energy when falling, which gets turned to heat when it hits the ground and stops moving. Heat flow is another issue, and is not accounted for.

Comment: One other thing not accounted for by the simple potential energy calculation is that the water might well be reaching terminal velocity for a given droplet size, thus losing some energy by heating the air.

Answer (score 2):

Most, if not all, scientific analysis of real situations involves approximations.

If some of the kinetic energy gained from falling was converted to kinetic energy of downstream flow (like a more sliding board shaped waterfall) it could affect the calculation.

The environment could affect the temperature of the pool of water at the bottom of the falls, especially if the volume is large compare to the flow rate.  In the winter there can be massive amounts of ice which would have a significant effect.

Gravity isn't really constant either, but changes with the position of the Sun, Moon and Earth. Gravity at the top of the falls will be less than at the bottom. Heat capacity isn't constant. Some of the water could evaporate on the way down the falls, cooling the water.  Niagara river isn't pure water. :)

For educational problems, especially if you want to do well on tests, you need to consider the spirit of the problem.

Comment: The effects due the change in $g$ with altitude and heat capacity with temperature are insignificant compared to the omission of kinetic energy.  If this was a Newtonian mechanics problem about a ball falling, I would just set $\frac{1}{2}mv^2=mgh$ to find the final velocity and there would be no change in internal energy whatsoever.  Why does Pauling assume that the kinetic energy does not change?

Comment: Well, the question is worded "as the result of the conversion of potential energy into thermal energy", so the intial kinentic energy is worded out of the problem. You are correct that potential energy coverted to final kinetic energy is not worded out of the problem, but that particular waterfall falls very freely and the hits the water below almost perpendicular to the surface. The kinetic energy from falling isn't substantially changed to kinetic energy in the downstream direction. The example problem isn't intended to be a serious analysis of the waterfall.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom of Niagara Falls is in shadow, both because points northward, both for the reflecting fog clouds. Thereafter the rock average temperature is lower there then on top, quickly cooling the fallen water. The experience of ACuriousJim should implies that this effect can be more relevant than the others mentioned above, which just reduce the temperature increment.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, thermal energy *is* heat. Think about heat as atoms vibrating: The more vigorously they vibrate (i.e. the more kinetic energy they have), the hotter it gets. The relation between thermal and kinetic energy is summarized by the simple equation
$k_B T=m\langle v_x^2\rangle$, where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant and $\langle v_x^2\rangle $ the expectation for the velocity squared of the particles in some direction labeled $x$.

He doesnt take the heat flow between water and environment into account because, in such a short process, it is very reasonable to assume that the heat transfer is negligible.

Comment: The reason I thought he should take the heat transfer into account is that if we go along with Pauling in taking the kinetic energy constant, the water must be at terminal velocity for the duration of its fall. Then the potential energy that would otherwise go into speeding it up would go either into the internal energy of the water or the environment, via air resistance.  (Now that I think about it, the water would be doing work on the air molecules, not transferring heat to them.)